# How to correctly load und unload swf galleries for PORTFOLIO web site?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My problem looks like: I have five buttons and four of them are loading four different swf galleries into the main swf, the last one unloads all galleries. Each of them has exactly the same code, the only differeces are the locations of jpg files and swf files. Also each o them has the listeners `ADDTOSTAGE` and `REMOVEFROMSTAGE`, because i'm using the `stage` inside the gallery/swfs.
So when I enter the menu and load the first swf i don't get any output errors, when I click the `btn_back` he unloads the swf properly with no errors. And so on but only when i load only one gallery.
But when I, after loading the first gallery, want to click on another button and load second gallery then i got this error in output, so many times as many pictures are loaded inside the loaded swf/gallery:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Nie można uzyskać dostępu do właściwości lub metody dla odniesienia do obiektu null.
at DocObject/resizeMyDoc()
at DocObject/onResizeDoc()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.display::Stage/dispatchEvent()
at Miniaturka/onAddedToStage()
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
at Miniaturki/callback()
at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
at Miniaturka/onLoadComplete()
```

So my conclusion is that the problem is not inside the loaded swf but in the code of loading and unloading code of the mine swf. The only solution that I can find is: that when I click the second button the code should first unload the current swf, and when the unload is complete then immidietly load the another one. But I don't know how to write it. Can anyone help? So here is the code.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.display.Loader;

var _mainLoader:Loader;
var _currentContent:DisplayObject;
var url:URLRequest;
var loaded:Boolean = false;
var a:Array = new Array(s1_1_arch, s1_2_arch, s1_3_arch, s1_4_arch);
var swfList:Array = ["A0101.swf", "A0102.swf", "A0103.swf"];

//Initiate Loader, do it only once
function initiateLoader():void {
    _mainLoader = new Loader();
    _mainLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

function loadGallery(path:String):void {
    //Check if content previously loaded, unload it
    if (_currentContent != null) {
        removeChild(_currentContent);
        _currentContent = null;
        _mainLoader.unloadAndStop();
    }

    //Now load another one
    _mainLoader.load(new URLRequest[1]);
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    _currentContent = _mainLoader.content;
    //Add root DisplayObject of the loaded content to the display list
    stage.addChild(_currentContent);
}

function samClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (e.target)
    {

        case s1_1_arch :
        break;

        case s1_2_arch :
        break;      

        case s1_3_arch :
        break;  

        case s1_4_arch :
        break;  

    }
}

function samOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
    switch (e.target)
    {

        case s1_1_arch  : var sam1Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_1_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0.2, 0.5, true);
            break;
        case s1_2_arch : var sam2Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_2_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0.2, 0.5, true);
            break;
        case s1_3_arch : var sam3Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_3_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0.2, 0.5, true);
            break;
        case s1_4_arch : var sam4Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_4_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0.2, 0.5, true);
            break;
    }
}
function samOut(e:MouseEvent):void{
    switch (e.target)
    {

        case s1_1_arch : var sam1Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_1_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0.2, 1, 0.5, true);
            break;
        case s1_2_arch : var sam2Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_2_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0.2, 1, 0.5, true);
            break;
        case s1_3_arch : var sam3Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_3_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0.2, 1, 0.5, true);
            break;
        case s1_4_arch : var sam4Ou:Tween = new Tween(s1_4_arch, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0.2, 1, 0.5, true);
            break;
    }
}

for (var i:Number = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    a[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, samClick);
    a[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, samOver);
    a[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, samOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. But you have many problems in your code, most of your switches are redundant. By default, all galleries, that you are loading, will be loaded in child `ApplicationDomains`, so they are suitable for garbage collection.

If you will use single `Loader` it will be easier for you to manage it, and load one section in time.

```
//Pseudo code
Create main loader (with onComplete event handler);
Create a function for loading content, and call it. 
Check if previous load operation was successful (use your flag `loaded`), if Yes - unload previous content, remove previous content from the display list;
Load new content;
After loading is completed, add content to the main display list holder, designed to show gallery content.
```

Also I would recommend to use [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), It's also more developer friendly.

Here for you several utility functions that will help you accomplish your task:

```
private var _mainLoader:Loader;
private var _currentContent:DisplayObject;

//Initiate Loader, do it only once
private function initiateLoader():void {
    _mainLoader = new Loader();
    _mainLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

private function loadGallery(path:String):void {
    //Check if content previously loaded, unload it
    if (_currentContent != null) {
        removeChild(_currentContent);
        _currentContent = null;
        _mainLoader.unloadAndStop();
    }

    //Now load another one
    _mainLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));
}

private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    _currentContent = _mainLoader.content;
    //Add root DisplayObject of the loaded content to the display list
    addChild(_currentContent);
}
```

More concrete realisation, you could use it in your frame, but don't forget to do all imports, and create all necessary display object on the scene:

```
//Self explanatory
var currentContent:DisplayObject;

//Initiate Loader
var mainLoader:Loader = new Loader();
mainLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

//Create some MovieClip and give it a name, you will place loaded content there, ex: contentHolder

//Add buttons in one container (MovieClip) and give it name, ex: buttonHolder
//Give buttons some names, ex: s1Arch, s2Arch, s3Arch
//Map our buttons to external links and prepare for mouse events
var links:Object = {"s1Arch": "A0101.swf", "s2Arch": "A0102.swf", "s3Arch": "A0103.swf"};
//Register listeners, you could do it in cycle
s1Arch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);
s2Arch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);
s3Arch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);

//Mouse events, using events bubbling
buttonHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);

function loadGallery(path:String):void {
    //Check if content previously loaded, unload it
    if (currentContent != null) {
        contentHolder.removeChild(currentContent);
        currentContent = null;
        mainLoader.unloadAndStop();
    }

    //Now load another one
    mainLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));
}

function onClickButton(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //Explanation step-by-step
    //Clicked button
    var button: DisplayObject = DisplayObject(e.currentTarget);
    //Path to the external file
    var path: String = links[button.name];
    //Utility function will handle another stuff
    loadGallery(path);
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    currentContent = mainLoader.content;
    //Add root DisplayObject of the loaded content to the display list
    contentHolder.addChild(currentContent);
}
```

Comment: So, i tried to figure it out with what you write to me and I can clearly see what you wan't to do, but i'm not so advance in as3, and I couldn't adapt the code, to mine. 
First I wanted to tell, that i didn't want to use it as a class, so I removed all 'private'. In the first post, i pasted the code i was tryging to create with help of yours. I created an empty stage, with four button, it will be for me more clear to work so, and when it'll work, then i will put it into the main file...
Could you please give me some more advice/help?

Comment: Uh oh, it will be many lines of code. I'm not sure that you will be able to port solution that I will provide you.

Comment: I have added more concrete example

Comment: I tried to use the concrete example of yours, and it worked, but i get still the 'Error #1009:' that I was writing aboute in the first post ;/...
-_-

Answer (score 0):

Just to add...

For something like this you are better of having all code in one place. A class file will save you other frustrations later on if you're still new. Just control all elements from one place. Also consider what Nicolas Siver said in his answer..

Just a quick guide on how to setup class file. If you save as Main.as and attach to your FLA then you can paste in your timeline code here.

```
package  
{

  //IMPORTS go here

  //Declare your Class (name of .as file)
  public class Main extends MovieClip 
  {
      //VARS go here 

      //Declare main function of your Class (must have same name as Class (.as file)
      public function Main() 
      {
        // Your main program code go here
        //Something(); //example: run a function called Something  

      }

      public function Something();
      {
         // Do something code
      } 

  } //End of Class 

} //End of Package
```

Comment: Thank's for your tip, I used classes before, but i always wondered what are the biggest benefits of using them ?

Comment: Its the best way to code as in effeciency and centralization. Ever had to click into X amount of movieClips just to get to that layer with a sprite just to change one line of code? Ever had "undefined" Var errors just because you were on a frame and some other relevant code is on a different frame elsewhere? Maybe you haven't pushed that hard with AS3 yet. When you start working regularly with classes you'll "feel" the benefits yourself and understand why that option is there